# Does a Warblade lose Battle Clarity when blinded?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, conditions, tome-of-battle, blind

Warblades gain an insight bonus to Reflex saves from Battle Clarity as long as they are not flat-footed.

Being blinded, characters lose their DEX bonus to AC, although doesn't specially mention them being flat-footed.

Can Warblades keep Battle Clarity when blind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## He does not, as he does not automatically get *Flat-footed* if *Blinded*

Let us try to analyze that as written, word by word.

Flat-footed is:

> A character who has not yet acted during a combat is flat-footed, not yet reacting normally to the situation. A flat-footed character loses his Dexterity bonus to AC (if any) and cannot make attacks of opportunity.

Battle Clarity is:

> Battle Clarity (Ex): You can enter a state of almost mystical awareness of the battlefield around you. As long as you are not flat-footed, you gain an insight bonus equal to your Intelligence bonus (maximum equals your warblade level) on your Reflex saves.

Blinded is:

> The character cannot see. He takes a -2 penalty to Armor Class, loses his Dexterity bonus to AC (if any), moves at half speed, and takes a -4 penalty on Search checks and on most Strength- and Dexterity-based skill checks. All checks and activities that rely on vision (such as reading and Spot checks) automatically fail. All opponents are considered to have total concealment (50% miss chance) to the blinded character. Characters who remain blinded for a long time grow accustomed to these drawbacks and can overcome some of them.

Which means that even though you don't get your Dex bonus to AC while blinded, if you have already acted during combat and/or already react normally to the situation, Battle Clarity does work for you.

There are many entities in D&D 3.5e that seem to be identical or almost identical, or even use almost equal wording, but are not actually completely same. ***While being blind and being flat-footed both make you lose your Dex bonux to AC, they are not the same.***

Answer (score 2):

## No, blindness is not the same as being flat-footed

*Tome of Battle: The Book of Nine Swords*, p. 22 says:

> Battle Clarity (Ex): You can enter a state of almost mystical awareness of the battlefield around you. As long as you are not flat-footed, you gain an insight bonus equal to your Intelligence bonus (maximum equals your warblade level) on your Reflex saves.

While being [blind](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#blinded) shares some of the drawbacks of being [flat-footed](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#flat-footed) (no Dexterity bonus to AC, unable to make Attacks of Opportunity due to [total concealment](http://dndsrd.net/combatModifiers.html#total-concealment)), they are not the same condition. According to the SRD, you are only flat-footed if you have not yet acted during a combat, or if an ability or condition specifically causes you to be come flat-footed.

The beginning statement in the Battle Clarity ability even shows that this *may* be as intended, as it says that you "enter a state of almost mystical awareness of the battlefield", which may not require vision.